# Node-Red MQTT publish node fails to connect to mosquitto broker when websockets are enabled

Tags: websocket, mqtt, node-red, mosquitto

Mosquitto config:

```
per_listener_settings true
listener 1883
protocol mqtt
listener 9001
protocol websockets
require_certificate false
log_type all
allow_anonymous true
```

In Node-Red, I have an MQTT Publish node set to publish to localhost:1883.

When I run mosquitto without the `listener 9001` and `protocol websockets` lines, node-red successfully connects and publishes to a topic. But I need websockets for a react application. When I run it with websockets on port 9001, I get the following error in mosquitto:

```
New connection from 127.0.0.1:61482 on port 1883.
Sending CONNACK to nodered_7b952a504a975460 (0, 5)
Client nodered_7b952a504a975460 disconnected, not authorised.
```

I've even tried using the websocket as the url for the node-red publish node like this:
`ws://localhost:9001` and `ws://localhost:9001/mqtt`. Neither works.

What do I have to do to be able to publish from node-red to my react app via a local mosquitto broker?

Comment: What version of Node-RED and mosquitto are you running?

Comment: Mosquitto 2.0.14. Node-RED 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove `per_listener_settings true` from the config file. I didn't realize I had it in there at first. Unfortunately, I do not know why this is the case.

Comment: You had to do this because with `per_listener_settings true` the `allow_anonymous true` becomes a per-listener setting (so you would need to include it twice, adding the second entry directly under `listener 1883`).

Comment: And with that missing from the original config file in the question we could not have answered this.